# Found a bug in mongoosastic or not

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I found a bug on mongoosastic, is that whenever I delete all of my user's data from mongodb, for somehow if I do `User.search()` , it is still showing the user's data, although I already deleted my user's data.

Possibly the data has not yet deleted in the elasticsearch itself. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like there is an open issue regarding this point: https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/137 + https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/114 . Would it work if you call `esTruncate`?

Comment: How do i run esTruncate ?

Comment: I did run esTruncate before createMapping, seems like the data is still there.

Comment: You have an example [here](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/92)

Comment: Let me try to run the example first.

Comment: esTruncate didn't delete the data. What is your opinion to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know how to delete data from elasticsearch itself?

Comment: You can still use the official [`delete` REST endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html)

Comment: In the future, let say I want to push my application to production. Do you recommend me to use mongoosastic ? or you have alternative solution?

Comment: you need to tell more about your use case or my opinion will be just guess work. It sounds like what you want to achieve is not (yet) supported by mongoosastic, so you'll probably have better luck chiming in the two issues I linked to in my first comment in order to know what their roadmap is.

Comment: My use case is that whenever I delete the data in mongodb, I expect mongoosastic to do the same or elasticsearch. So that I don't need to delete it manually and How do i search my elasticsearch index?